# How do I define my proxy setting and SSL certificates for automating API calls in karate framework

Tags: automation, bdd, rest-assured, web-api-testing, karate

Can i pass the proxy host and port as config parameters from the karate-config.js file? How do we handle SSL certificates in Karate framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy, please refer to the documentation of the [`configure` keyword](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure).

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I am new to karate framework and BDD and your help has been very useful :D